# 値を中心として, 前後にある数だけ幅を取るために使用できるアルゴリズムがありますか

Tags: アルゴリズム

値を中心として, 前後にある数だけ幅を取るために使用できるアルゴリズムがありますか

例えばこの入力で平均値99を基準に, 幅を15とすると

```
98
174
58
49
78
90
75
170
```

下のような結果を期待しています.

```
36-51
52-67
68-83
84-99
100-115
116-131
132-147
148-163
164-179
```

これは平均値を求め, そこから順に幅を加算していけば求められますが, この手法では基準値より大きい数値と小さい数値で2回のループ処理が必要になります. これを逐次的, 効率的に行えるアルゴリズムはありますか.

なお, これは度数分布に用いるため, この後に各範囲に収まる数値の数を数え上げます. この背景も含め, より良い手法がございましたら, ご教授お願い致します.

Comment: 境界が飛んでいる気がします。例えば99.5はどのレンジにも入りません。

Comment: 「平均値99を基準」の平均値とは何の平均値なのでしょうか？　
質問に書かれている数値が「平均値99を基準」である事は、どのようにして証明できるのでしょうか？
「左右にある数」というのは、どういう意味でしょうか。二つの数があったときに、その左右を決定するのは何なのでしょうか？

Comment: どの程度のデータ数を想定していますか。どのぐらいの頻度で使用することを想定していますか。データ数、使用頻度によって、アルゴリズムが変わるかもしれません。

Comment: @erinix 整数に丸められているので, 小数点以下は考慮しません.

Comment: アルゴリズムを考えるときに大事なのは「入力」と「出力」です。へかてさんの想定されているアルゴリズムは、入力として「99」「5」だけが与えられれば、質問文にある6行が出力されるようなものなのでしょうか。他に入力は必要ありませんか？（へかてさんがどんなアルゴリズムを欲されているのかいまいち理解できなかったので質問してみています）

Comment: @Fumu7 データ群の代表値です. これは事前に1つだけ与えられています. コードブロックで表現したように幅を取りたいことを言いたかったのですが, 左右という表現はわかりづらいため削除しました.

Comment: @nekketsuuu 具体的な入力と結果を追記しました. ご確認お願いします.

Comment: 恐らく「98 ... 170」の8つの数値が入力で、これらから求めた平均値が99ということですよね？ / 数値の左右は恐らく数直線をイメージされているのかもしれませんが、前後とか上下の方が分かりやすいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick はい, そうです. / 前後に修正しました.

Comment: 何かしら既存のプログラムがあるけどそれでは効率が悪いと感じているからほかの方法はないか？…という事であれば、既存のプログラムなりも載せてもらった方が回答する側も (やりたいことが) 理解しやすくなると思います、

Answer (score 2):

質問者さんの考えてらっしゃるアルゴリズムより飛びぬけて早くなる逐次アルゴリズムは無いと考えて良いです。

まず、入力データである数値列が与えられた時点で、その平均値・最小値・最大値が計算できます。このとき入力データの走査は1回だけです。平均値を知るために必ず1回は走査しないといけないので、これは最小回数です。

そのあと「幅」を計算する訳ですが、小さい方と大きい方でループが2個あるとはいえ、出力されるはずの「幅」たちがちょうど1回ずつ出力されるのみです。ここの計算時間のオーダーは O(N) であり、O(N²) ではないことに注意してください（ループがネストしている訳ではありません）。「幅」を全部出力するためには必ず1回は走査しないといけないので、やはり最小回数です。具体的な出力方法によってはほんの少しだけ無駄があるかもしれませんが、ほぼ無駄は無いと考えて良いでしょう。

したがって、質問者さんの考えてらっしゃるアルゴリズムで既に充分効率的です。

ループをひとつにしたいのであれば、最小値 `v` について `平均値 + (幅 + 1) * ((v - 平均値) / (幅 + 1))` ( `/` は整数の除算) を計算するなどすれば最初の「幅」が分かるので、ここを始点としてループを始めれば良いです。

Comment: 補足として、この方式でアルゴリズムを組んだ場合、メモリ計算量は O(1) なので、その意味でも十分に効率的だと考えられます。